# fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Alchemy\BinaryDriver\Exception\ExecutableNotFoundException' with message 'Executable not found, proposed

Tags: php, ffmpeg, video-processing, ffmpeg-php

I have installed https://github.com/PHP-FFMpeg/PHP-FFMpeg on linux

hosting path is

```
/public_html/videoconversion/
```

I got this error.

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Alchemy\BinaryDriver\Exception\ExecutableNotFoundException' with message 
'Executable not found, proposed : 
    public_html/videoconversion/' in 
        /home/deveducate/public_html/videoconversion/vendor/alchemy/binary-driver/src/Alchemy/BinaryDriver/AbstractBinary.php:160 Stack trace: 
        #0 /home/deveducate/public_html/videoconversion/vendor/php-ffmpeg/php-ffmpeg/src/FFMpeg/Driver/FFProbeDriver.php(48): 
            Alchemy\BinaryDriver\AbstractBinary::load('public_html/vid...', NULL, Object(Alchemy\BinaryDriver\Configuration)) 
        #1 /home/deveducate/public_html/videoconversion/vendor/php-ffmpeg/php-ffmpeg/src/FFMpeg/FFProbe.php(226): FFMpeg\Driver\FFProbeDriver::create(Array, NULL) 
        #2 /home/deveducate/public_html/videoconversion/vendor/php-ffmpeg/php-ffmpeg/src/FFMpeg/FFMpeg.php(117): FFMpeg\FFProbe::create(Array, NULL, NULL) 
        #3 /home/deveducate/public_html/videoconversion/convert_to_mp4.php(10): FFMpeg\FFMpeg::create(Array, NULL) 
        #4 {main} Next exception 'FFMpeg\Exception\ExecutableNotFoundException' with message 
           'U in /home/deveducate/public_html/videoconversion/vendor/php-ffmpeg/php-ffmpeg/src/FFMpeg/Driver/FFProbeDriver.php on line 50
```

file

```
require 'vendor/autoload.php';
$ffmpeg = FFMpeg\FFMpeg::create(array(
'ffmpeg.binaries'  => '/opt/local/ffmpeg/bin/ffmpeg',
'ffprobe.binaries' => '/opt/local/ffmpeg/bin/ffprobe',
'timeout'          => 3600, // The timeout for the underlying process
'ffmpeg.threads'   => 12,   // The number of threads that FFMpeg should 
 use
 ), $logger);
 $video = $ffmpeg->open('video.mpg');
$video
->filters()
->resize(new FFMpeg\Coordinate\Dimension(320, 240))
->synchronize();
$video
->frame(FFMpeg\Coordinate\TimeCode::fromSeconds(10))
->save('frame.jpg');
$video
->save(new FFMpeg\Format\Video\X264(), 'export-x264.mp4')
```

May any one let me know where to update path.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Per the [documentation](https://github.com/PHP-FFMpeg/PHP-FFMpeg):

> FFMpeg will autodetect ffmpeg and ffprobe binaries. If you want to give binary paths explicitly, you can pass an array as configuration.

Example:

```
$ffmpeg = FFMpeg\FFMpeg::create(array(
    'ffmpeg.binaries'  => '/opt/local/ffmpeg/bin/ffmpeg',
    'ffprobe.binaries' => '/opt/local/ffmpeg/bin/ffprobe',
    'timeout'          => 3600, // The timeout for the underlying process
    'ffmpeg.threads'   => 12,   // The number of threads that FFMpeg should use
), $logger);
```

In your code, it looks like you need to make the changes in this file:

> /home/deveducate/public_html/videoconversion/convert_to_mp4.php

NOTE: It also says this in the docs, so you may be able to just add them to the system path:

> This library requires a working FFMpeg install. You will need both FFMpeg and FFProbe binaries to use it. Be sure that these binaries can be located with system PATH to get the benefit of the binary detection, otherwise you should have to explicitly give the binaries path on load.

Comment: its not working i added the above code in convert_to_mp4.php

Comment: That was a sample code, I assume you modified it to fit your project?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue and finally resolved it:

- Make sure ffmpeg is installed (`apt get install ffmpeg`)
- In addition, if you have a PHP `openbasedir` restriction, make sure to add ffmpeg and ffprobe to it:
  `open_basedir="/tmp:/usr/share/php::/usr/bin/ffmpeg:/usr/bin/ffprobe"`

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem and solved it by the following steps:

1. ffmpeg needs to be installed on your system. Use the following command to install ffmpeg in Linux:

   sudo apt install ffmpeg
2. You need to modify Open_basedir conf in PHP parameters of your domain:

   {WEBSPACEROOT}{/}{:}{TMP}{/}:/usr/bin/ffmpeg:/usr/bin/ffprobe
3. Finally there needs to be a timeout parameter in your php code:

   $ffmpeg = FFMpeg\FFMpeg::create(
   array(
   'timeout' => 0,
   )
   );